# Removing duplicates from an array using std::map

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm

I'm directly posting my code which I've written on **collabedit** under 5 minutes (including figuring out the algorithm) thus even though with the risk of completely made of fun in terms of efficiency I wanted to ask my fellow experienced stack overflow algorithm enthusiasts about the problem;

Basically removing duplicate elements from an array. **My Approach:** Basically using the **std::map** as my hash table and for each element in duplicated array if the value has not been assigned add it to our new array. If assigned just skip. At the end return the unique array. Here is my code and the only thing I'm asking in terms of an interview question can my solution be more efficient?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

vector<int>uniqueArr(int arr[],int size){
    std::map<int,int>storedValues;
    vector<int>uniqueArr;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(storedValues[arr[i]]==0){
            uniqueArr.push_back(arr[i]);
            storedValues[arr[i]]=1;
        }
    }
    return uniqueArr;  
}

int main()
{   
    const int size=10;
    int arr[size]={1,2,2,4,2,5,6,5,7,1};
    vector<int>uniArr=uniqueArr(arr,size);
    cout<<"Result: ";
    for(int i=0;i<uniArr.size();i++) cout<<uniArr[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the question specifically ask you to do it in C++, or did you just choose it yourself?

Comment: @James It's the language that I feel most comfortable with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there is no need for a map, a set is conceptually more correct, since you don't want to store any values, but only the keys.

Performance-wise, it might be a better idea to use a `std::unordered_set` instead of a `std::set`, as the former is hashed and can give you O(1) insert and lookup in best case, whereas the latter is a binary search tree, giving you only O(log n) access.

```
vector<int> uniqueArr(int arr[], int size)
{
    std::unordered_set<int> storedValues;
    vector<int> uniqueArr;
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i){
        if(storedValues.insert(arr[i]).second)
            uniqueArr.push_back(arr[i]);
    return uniqueArr;  
}
```

But if you are allowed to use the C++ standard library more extensively, you may also consider the other answers using `std::sort` and `std::unique`, although they are **O(n log n)** (instead of the above **~O(n)** solution) and destroy the order of the elements.

---

If you want to use a more flexible and std-driven approach but with ~O(n) complexity and without destroying the order of the elements, you can transform the above routine into the following std-like algorithm, even if being a bit too far-fetched for a simple interview question:

```
template<typename ForwardIterator>
ForwardIterator unordered_unique(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type value_type;
    std::unordered_set<value_type> unique;
    return std::remove_if(first, last, 
                          [&unique](const value_type &arg) mutable -> bool
                              { return !unique.insert(arg).second; });
}
```

Which you can then apply like `std::unique` in the usual erase-remove way:

```
std::vector<int> values(...);
values.erase(unordered_unique(values.begin(), values.end()), values.end());
```

To remove the unique values without copying the vector and without needing to sort it beforehand.

Comment: Great explanation. I still do not wish to use **too much** std's. I've focused more than solving the problem in a short period of time, focusing on the algorithm.

Comment: @rolandbishop Well, a hash is really a pretty standard data structure, that is there in nearly every language (even if the C++ standards committee needed some time to realize this). If you are confident to use a `std::map`, there is no objection against a `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: I know silly but what is the difference here between using the **unordered_set** and **vector** . Forgive me if it is too silly to ask but in terms of storing only integers and providing O(1) aren't both of them do the same? Does **set** have any upper-hand?

Comment: @rolandbishop The problem with a vector is, it has O(1) insert, but only O(n) lookup (when you want to search if a certain value is in there). On the other hand a `std::set` being a binary tree gives you O(log n) insert and lookup. But a `std::unordered_set` being a hashed container can give you O(1) insert and lookup in best case (depending on the quality of the hash function, of course).

Comment: @rolandbishop Or you might also use a `std::vector` indexed by the value from the input array. This would indeed give you O(1) insert and lookup, too. But the problem is that you need to know the range of values in your input array and this range shouldn't be too large, whereas a hash set doesn't depend on the range of keys that heavily.

Comment: This was exactly why I was asking the question of vector vs set. Thank for the deep explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking in terms of an interview question, I will say that you don't get the job.

```
const int size=10;
int arr[size]={1,2,2,4,2,5,6,5,7,1};

std::sort( &arr[0], &arr[size] );
int* new_end = std::unique( &arr[0], &arr[size] );

std::copy(
    &arr[0], new_end,
  , std::ostream_iterator< int >( std::cout, " " )
);
```

No temporary maps, no temporary vectors, no dynamic memory allocations, a lot **less code** written so its easier both to write and to mantain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how come? Is it that inefficient? I believe my solution is **O(n)** so can you explain why I would not get the job :). Thanks again!

Comment: @rolandbishop: `std::sort` is usually _(if not always)_ implemented as _quicksort_. I believe `std::stable_sort` is usually implemented with some variant of _mergesort_, with a less critical worse case time. Note that the standard establishes complexity requirements for its algorithms, so rolling your own version would only make sense if you can beat those minimum requeriments.

Comment: I think this answer demonstrates familiarity with C++ rather than algorithm writing skills.

Comment: @K-ballo but this would be O(nlogn). Using a good hash table we can do this in O(n), can't we? BTW rolandbishop, map does not support O(1) search. It's implemented as a Red Black Tree.

Comment: @rolandbishop: If I was given your code I'd then ask you to write the algorithm for std::unique

Comment: @sukunrt Thanks a lot! I really did not know that. But in terms of an interview I guess I could get a pre-built hash table provided?

Comment: @rolandbishop What they're probably looking for is the histogram approach, but this is only really feasible if the range of the values is manageable. You'd populate the histogram with the values and then scan through it outputting the non-zero indexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec({1,2,3,2,4,4,5,7,6,6});
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    vec.erase(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end());
    // vec = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
    return 0;
}
//works with C++11
// O(n log n)
```

Answer (score 1):

In-place removal's nice for speed - something like this (returning the new size):

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t keep_unique(T (&array)[N])
{
    std::unordered_set<T> found;
    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < N; ++i)
        if (found.insert(array[i]).second))
            if (j != i) // (optional) avoid copy to self, as may be slower or unsupported by T
                array[j++] = array[i];
            else
                ++j;
    return j;
}
```

(For larger objects, or those that can't be safely copied, may be necessary and/or faster and more space efficient to store `T*`s in the unordered_set - must also provide a dereferencing comparison operator and hash function.)

To visualise how this works, consider processing the following input:

```
1  3  6  3  5  6  0  2  1
         <--+<----+  |
               <-----+
```

The arrows above represent the minimal in-place compaction necessary to produce the answer:

```
1  3  6  5  0  2
```

That's precisely what the algorithm above does, looking at all the elements at `[i]`, and keeping track of where they need to be copied to (and how many non-duplicates there are) in `[j]`.